# Python: Add column to panda data frame with different column length

Tags: dataframe, row

I have a panda dataframe and would like to add data columns using one common column as index. In case the new data does not have the index value it should enter a 0. The new column will have a different length. Is there a better way than using a loop? Example below

main Dataframe:

```
index_column    date   value
1               1       A
2               2       B
3               3       C
4               4       D
```

add new column:

```
date   value
2       G
3       J
```

Result:

```
index_column    date   value  new value
1               1       A       0
2               2       B       G
3               3       C       J
4               4       D       0
```

Many thanks!

Rolf

Comment: `df.merge(df2, on='date', how='left')`

Comment: thanks! I had some problems with indices so used date column index and then used left_index = True and right_index=True